# How are we to interpret the logos with God in the beginning?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

We've all heard of the Gospel of John and "In the beginning was the logos and the logos was with God."  Many commentators and scholars have etymologically traced the term back to the notion of Word or revelation, whether in the sense of creation itself or scripture.  Others have suggested this actually means the "gathering" or the divine act manifesting God's personality.  A fascinating account of personality is given by one of the greatest thinkers of our age, Henri Bergson.  For Bergson, personality as "inaction" boils down to the storing of energy that needs to be let out or released and acted upon.  Its mark or articulation lies in the hesitation and gesture which precedes any action.

Given the several hermeneutical claims it is puzzling as to what the phrase is meant to capture and express:  was it God's word, or act, or even hesitation in the beginning?

Comment: Voting to close, as both Biblical Hermeneutics and Christianity are better fits for this question than Philosophy.  It is neither philosophy nor does philosophical training help one answer this question (except inasmuch as philosophical training may help one answer arbitrary questions).  Did you actually mean to post it here?

Comment: Should your justification really be extending the question by 200%? Voting to edit.

Comment: Yeah, this seems problematic to me. Note there's plenty of great questions about philosophy of religion on this site; I might try comparing their tone and scope to your question and see if there are elements you might be able to improve. It seems to me the greater part of the content here is only vaguely related to the problem you're posing (and might really be more appropriately formulated on meta.) Please consider cleaning this up a bit, focusing on one concern, and giving us a little more on the context and motivations of your problem and what sort of explanation you might be expecting

Comment: @MyronMosesJackson: I've edited your question to prune it back to its original form, as your remarks were not on the same topic as the question. If you're concerned about censorship or that the Philosophy.SE forum is being too narrow, that might be an appropriate topic to raise on the "Philosophy Meta" forum. Alternatively, if you have specific concerns about how the specialization in philosophy might affect discourse, it is conceivable that you could ask that as a separate Philosophy question, (though I would suggest considering the general phenomenon, detached from this specific question).

Comment: Definitely much more focused without those remarks; please note that great questions ask about some specific problem -- keep in mind you can always ask more! At any rate it would be great if you could revise your post to include a little more of the context and motivations of the concern here and maybe share a little bit more about the sort of answer you might be looking for.

Comment: I agree with the closure. This is not constructive as posed. The topic isn't inherently outside the scope of philosophy but without any sources or references, it will generate poor answers; i.e. "debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  If you look at Heidegger's Was ist Denken, which he gave after his five-year teaching ban, you will see he devotes most of the analysis to the hermeneutics of logos.  He later addresses this in a theological context in his lectures on Poetry, Language, and Truth.  Another suggestion goes against Heidegger and argues logos should be interpreted as "proportionality."  My bad, maybe I should have put it in a logical context to feed the analytical fetish.

Comment: Well thanks a lot, man!  That is embarrassing...hahaha!  Guess we all owe each other one.  Appreciate you, Joseph

Comment: @MyronMosesJackson: analytical or no, I'm not sure how anyone without specific religious training would be able to answer the question. I couldn't get any traction to start thinking about the problem despite a Christian upbringing, for example, because unless I am to interpret the word as 'idea', 'the phenomenon of language', or 'law', it doesn't make a lot of sense; and any answer I might give would be pure speculation as to what the early authors of the Bible wanted to say.

Comment: Given the question is filed under the philosophy of religion; given also that Zizek has written on Christianity too (his *St Pauls*) I don't understand why this question is so problematic - perhaps it is my understanding of what this category designates. How one is suppose to philosophise about a religion without understanding what it is about seems to me odd. Is one expected to situate religion structurally as in levi-strauss structural anthropology - surely this is only one mode of objective investigation.